# Ubuntu 12.10 LTS Wont show my connected Audio outputs

Tags: 12.10, sound, lts

When I plug my headphones in I will hear and see nothing from that output.
Nothing happens when I plug my output in, it will stay the same.

Help is really appriciated since I need my sound back as soon as possable

[EDIT]

Heres my Alsamixer setting, since so many people are asking for it, and I cannot post pictures since my reputation is to low

```
Card: HDA NVidia                                     F1:  Help               │
│ Chip: Realtek ALC662 rev1                            F2:  System information │
│ View: F3:[Playback] F4: Capture  F5: All             F6:  Select sound card  │
│ Item: Master [dB gain: 0,00]                         Esc: Exit               │

 100    100<>100 100<>100   0<>0   100<>100 100<>100   100      100

< Master >  PCM     Front   Front Mi Front Mi Surround  Center    LFE   


0<>0                                0<>0     0<>0

Line    S/PDIF  S/PDIF D Channel  Rear Mic<Rear Mic>
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of `alsamixer`?

Comment: Look at the edited question, there are all my settings of it, expept for the bars, they get placed wrong, making it really wierd and hard to see whats going on in the terminal (the bars are correctly placed in the terminal)

Answer (score 0):

Check alsamixer (type it in terminal) levels. Also, check pulseaudio configuration. If you don't have pulseaudio installed, install it along with pavucontrol via Ubuntu Software Center or Synaptic. Once this is done, open the Pulseaudio Volume Control and check your settings. It'd be wise that your headphones are plugged in and some audio application is generating sound output, so you'll see if the configuration is correct while sending the output to your headphones.

Comment: Pick analog output

Comment: The Pavucontrol is showing me that the headphones are emitting sound, meanwhile i dont hear anything. Alsamixer is just doing nothing with the sound, it looks like the bars are frozen or sometihing like that. Do i need to select a output or press a butten or something?

Comment: Are you on a laptop or a desktop? Sometimes desktops have front plug holes and rear plug holes, try both. Also make sure to plug the cable into the green hole. When in alsamixer check that Master is at 100, Headphones at 100, PCM at 100. In alsamixer move yourself using the arrow keys on your keyboard

Comment: What I meant was that if you are using a desktop computer or a laptop.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Im on a PC, and all the setting you said to change to are done, i dont hear anything, and still the program says its emmiting sound. Heres my Alsamixer settings                   Card: HDA NVidia                                                                               │
│ Chip: Realtek ALC662 rev1                                                       F2:  System information │
│ View: F3:[Playback] F4: Capture  F5: All                                        F6:  Select sound card  │
│ Item: PCM [dB gain: 0,00, 0,00]

Comment: │     100    100<>100 100<>100   0<>0   100<>100 100<>100   100      100      0<>0                        │
│    Master <  PCM   > Front   Front Mi Front Mi Surround  Center    LFE      Line    S/PDIF  S/PDIF D    │
│

Comment: In pavucontrol (pulseaudio GUI) go to the output devices tab and select analog headphones. Check that the output is not mute and it's not selected as Plan B, also check for hardware failure (broken plug of headphones).